# Select most recent MAX() and MIN() - WebSQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite, web-sql

i'm build an exercises web app and i'm working with two tables like this:

Table 1: weekly_stats

```
| id |    code      |      type          |       date |     time |
|----|--------------|--------------------|------------|----------|
|  1 |           CC |                  1 | 2015-02-04 | 19:15:00 |
|  2 |           CC |                  2 | 2015-01-28 | 19:15:00 |
|  3 |          CPC |                  1 | 2015-01-26 | 19:15:00 |
|  4 |          CPC |                  1 | 2015-01-25 | 19:15:00 |
|  5 |           CP |                  1 | 2015-01-24 | 19:15:00 |
|  6 |           CC |                  1 | 2015-01-23 | 19:15:00 |
| .. |          ... |                ... |    ...     |    ...   |
```

Table 2: global_stats

```
| id | exercise_number |correct |   wrong   |
|----|-----------------|--------|-----------|
|  1 |             138 |      1 |         0 |
|  2 |             246 |      1 |         0 |
|  3 |             988 |      1 |        10 |
|  4 |              13 |      5 |         0 |
|  5 |               5 |      4 |         7 |
|  6 |               5 |      4 |         7 |
| .. |             ... |    ... |       ... |
```

What i would like is to get MAX(correct-wrong) and MIN(correct-wrong) and now i'm working with this query:

```
SELECT
  exercise_number,
  date,
  time
FROM weekly_stats AS w JOIN global_stats AS g
ON w.id=g.id 
WHERE correct - wrong = (SELECT MAX(correct - wrong) from global_stats)
UNION
SELECT
  exercise_number,
  date,
  time
FROM weekly_stats AS w JOIN global_stats AS g
ON w.id=g.id 
WHERE correct - wrong = (SELECT MIN(correct - wrong) from global_stats);
```

This query is working good, except for one thing: when "WHERE correct - wrong = (SELECT MIN(correct - wrong)[...]" selects more than one row, **the row selected is the first but i would like to have returned the most recent (in other words: ordered by datetime(date, time)).** Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if it's just a question of result ordering, then perhaps adding `ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC` to each of the component queries would give you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      1 as sort_column,
      exercise_number,
      date,
      time
    FROM weekly_stats AS w JOIN global_stats AS g
    ON w.id=g.id 
    WHERE correct - wrong = (SELECT MAX(correct - wrong) from global_stats)
    ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
    LIMIT 1 ) as a
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      2 as sort_column,
      exercise_number,
      date,
      time
    FROM weekly_stats AS w JOIN global_stats AS g
    ON w.id=g.id 
    WHERE correct - wrong = (SELECT MIN(correct - wrong) from global_stats)
    ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
LIMIT 1) as b
ORDER BY sort_column;
```

Here is the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) about how UNION works.

Comment: you're right, I updated the answer. Can you try that?

Comment: Now it's working, but also causing a new problem: now also the 2 rows returned are ordered by date... now how can i understand which one is the result of MAX() and one is the result of MIN()?

Comment: The new problem is not caused by the internal orders. Thats how UNION works (according to documentation: "..use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.."). Changed the answer to include order of the whole set.

Comment: Thanks Bardh, thanks also for the link to the documentation, as you may have guessed i'm learning MySQL/SQLite so any hint is always precious:)